# Refactoring Large Classes using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, refactoring

I am currently migrating a very large and fairly old MVC web application to .NET 6.0.  Some of the legacy POCO classes contain Properties that refer to other services within the solution.  In particular, some of the classes may have a dozen different properties that depend on a dozen different services, like this:

```
public bool HasPledge
{
    get
    {
        PledgeService service = new PledgeService();

        return service.HasPledge(this.Id);
    }
}
```

What I want to know is, how can I refactor these classes so that they are not so tightly coupled to a whole bunch of other services.  Should I

1. Convert the Properties to Methods and inject individual services into them
2. Inject all (12) required services into the constructor
3. Look for some other way to reduce these classes' dependencies

I hope that makes sense.  I'm only just coming around to the DI paradigm although I can certainly see the benefits (just wish I'd seen the benefits 10 years ago!).

Thanks

Comment: 1. looks cumbersome, 2. relatively the easiest, 3. best but is going to take a lot time.

Comment: If they are POCOs then get rid of the dependencies. Create a service or services with the dependencies on the other services and let them create your POCOs but keep the POCOs clean of dependencies.